# Node.js modules: correct way to refer to sibling functions

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is my current code:

```js
var PermissionsChecker = {};

PermissionsChecker.check = function(id) {
  PermissionsChecker.getPermissions(id);
}

PermissionsChecker.getPermissions = function(id) {
  // do stuff
}
```

Two questions:

1. Is this the right way to construct node.js functions?
2. Is that line in `.check` the correct way to refer to a sibling function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly fine. Some notes:

- *Sibling function* isn't really any standard term for methods of the same object. Minor note, but could cause confusion.
- When a function is called as a method on some object, then the value of `this` inside that function refers to the object on which it was called. That is, calling `check` like this:

  ```
  PermissionsChecker.check()
  ```

  ...allows you to write the function like this:

  ```
  PermissionsChecker.check = function(id) {
      this.getPermissions(id);
  }
  ```

  ...which is more succinct and probably more common.
- Nothing about your question is specific to node.js. This applies to JavaScript in the browser (or anywhere else), too.
- You could save some typing by rewriting your example like this:

  ```
  var PermissionsChecker = {
      check: function(id) {
          this.getPermissions(id);
      },
      getPermissions: function(id) {
          // do stuff
      }
  };
  ```

Answer (score 2):

So long as the function is called with `PermissionsChecker.check()`, you can refer to the object with `this`.

[CodePad](http://ideone.com/ZevCA).

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for putting an example up.

Answer (score 2):

What you've done above is called an object literal, but you could choose the prototypal way also (when you need to instantiate objects - OOP stuff).

You can call this inside to refer to another object property:

```
PermissionsChecker.check = function(id) {
  this.getPermissions(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for that. I ended up doing that.